# Error with accessing one fuction in pywin32 or win32com from python 3.3.5

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32, win32com

I've generated a win32com wrapper for a DLL and I'm trying to access it. It works except for one function called ReadPipeBytes. It works on two of my other machines but I'm using a different python version. This is the error:'' object has no attribute 'ReadPipeBytes'. I copied over the same dll to the other machine (its a driver, I have the same hardware I'm trying to access.) I did a compare on the wrapper files and they are almost identical except for the python versions they were generated with and the 3.3.5 generated version doesn't put u'FunctionName' where the 2.7 version does. If I copy over the wrapper file to the machine that doesn't work I get the same error (and/or the dict file).

1) Why would the version of python make a difference in reading this one particular function when the other function work fine (its not the wrapper?

2) How can python fail to use the function called readpipebytes when the other functions work and when I'm using the same files that I do on my other machines?

Comment: Is the Python version on the machine where it does not work maybe a 64bit one?

Comment: Yes, but I have it working on a different 64bit machine, the caveat there is due a crazy pywin32 install I have 2.7.5 version of pywin32 running from 3.3.2 python. Both the working and non-working machines are 64-bit windows7. On a separate machine I have it running on 32-bit windows xp with no problems. Maybe it doesn't like 64-bit?

Comment: I don't think you can use a Py2.7 version of pywin32 with Py3.x and you can't mix 32 and 64 bit stuff.  In other words if you use Py3.x 64 bit then all the libraries etc you use with that version of Python have to be 64 bit - no expert here but that is my understanding.

Comment: I've installed 32-bit of Python 3.3.3 and pywin32 on a 64-bit machine with no luck. I did have success on a 32-bit machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use com the language you are accessing it from needs the same "bittedness" as the com .dll or control. So If you have a 32-bit control or com dll you have to have a 32 bit win32com.